# WPF: Issue with OverFlow Panel on Toolbar control

Tags: data-binding, wpf-controls, expression-blend, overflow, toolbar

I'm having an issue working with the Toolbar control for WPF in Blend 3:

I have a Toolbar control that is binded to a collection so that it displays both icons and labels for each one of the actions that users can perform on this application. The issue I'm having is that when I run the application the buttons are displayed inside the OverFlow Panel instead of the toolbar although there is a lot of space to fit them all inside the toolbar.

The only way of making them appear on their positions is resizing/maximizing the window, so I'm lost trying to figure out what's the reason for the icons to appear inside the overflow  panel if there aren't too many buttons used and enough space to fit them all?.

I'm including the following screenshot to make the issue clearer:

http://www.pgcoms.com/blend/toolbarCapture.PNG

Would really appreciate your help on this.
Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Whenever I have an issue like this its because a control is gobbling up all the available space.  Try setting the widths on your toolbar and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Will, have tried modifying the width but it behaves the same. Weird is that maximizing or resizing the window makes the control to display correctly without putting the buttons on the Overflow panel. Hope someone can help here!